# How implementation configuration in gradle is being enforced?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to dive deep into how gradle works and trying to understand its awesomeness. So i created two projects:

1) Project B which contains guava dependency as implementation, next i deployed this project using publishToMavenLocal task.

2) Project A which contains dependency to project B as implementation too. I was surprised when in project A i was free to use guava as transitive dependency.

And in documentation i found:

> The api configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are exported by the library API, whereas the implementation configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.

From what i know guava dependency should be invisible to my A project nonetheless i can depend on it. My question is: Why we need implementation configuration at all? How it is being enforced and in what situations ? Is implementation vs compile is changing somehow internally jars?